# update source package?

Tags: ros, arduino, update, rosserial, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'd like to apply changes mentioned here: https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/150
and here: http://answers.ros.org/question/197596/a-problem-in-transfering-neagtive-values-to-arduino-via-std_msgsfloat64/

Can someone tell me which package should I update and how to update it ?

I'm using ROS Hydro.

thanks in advance.

regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220664/update-source-package-?/) by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The merge seems to be only merged for indigo. You can try to just build the package from the indigo-devel branch in hydro. If that doesn't work easily, you need to backport the fix manually unless someone else has done that already.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0